# spinner defined in main activity is null

Tags: android

I have populated a spinner with items in xml file using entries option.  I have defined the spinner in main activity class as "s1". In debug mode i found that s1 is null.  That is why setOnItemSelectedListener is not working for spinner.  When an item is selected, toast message is not displayed.  I am giving mainactivity.java, activity_main.xml and strings.xml files.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
String[] presidents; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


if (savedInstanceState == null) {
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
.commit();
} 

presidents = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.presidents);

Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.array.presidents, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
if(s1 != null){
s1.setAdapter(adapter);

s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
{
int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), presidents[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){

}
});
}


}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawSelectorOnTop= "true"
android:entries="@array/presidents" />
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string-array name = "presidents">
<item>eisenhower</item>
<item>kennedy</item>
</string-array>   
</resources>
```

Comment: index should be arg2

Comment: u r using setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); but post xml fragment_main.xml

Comment: I am using fragment_main.xml in placeholderFragment class in the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is wrong, use `R.layout.fragment_main` instead

Comment: I am using R.layout.fragment_main in placeholderFragment class

Comment: yes, but your main activity is inflated by `activity_main.xml`, when you do `findViewById` for `spinner1` which is in `fragment_main` and not in `activity_main` is returned `null`. try to put the `spinner` code in `onCreateView()` of your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Spinner s1;
    private String[] presidents;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        presidents = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.presidents);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.presidents, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        if(s1 != null){
            s1.setAdapter(adapter);
            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, presidents[arg2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In debug mode, i found that spinner s1 is null.  How to set the value for s1.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized your Spinner at the class level. At this point, the Spinner object is null. You should instead initialize your Spinner within the onCreate() method. So you can have it like this:

```
Spinner s1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Only here is the layout inflated and only after this can Android see the Spinner

    s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // Other statements
}
```